# React Native: Suspense does not render the fallback view

Tags: react-native

I have created an empty project using react native cli. Here is the versions:

```
   "react": "18.2.0",
   "react-native": "0.71.6"
```

This is the App.tsx file:

```
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import React, {Suspense} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;

const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Hello!</Text>
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <View>
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
            <Text>Loading...</Text>
          </View>
        }>
        <MyComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the content of the Component.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

function loadData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("loaded data");
    }, 8000);
  });
}

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData().then((data) => {
      setData("This is test!!!");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{data}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I used `React.lazy()` to load a component, and then used `Suspense` to render the component as soon as the promise resolved. I expected React renders the fallback view before rendering `MyComponent`, but it does not seem to be doing so!

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your component is not taking enough time to render the fallback, you are just delaying the data loading inside of it but not the component itself.

If you want the fallback to be shown you have to delay the load of the component itself, see example below:

```
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
     resolve(import("./Component"));
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```